# Custom JSON response structure in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel

I have an application form which text data is stored in one table. Let's say table A (only one entry). The attachments are stored in table B which have multiple entries (since the user can add multiple attachments) and they are referenced by an application number.

I want to send the data as a JSON response which is what I am doing via a leftJoin clause. I noticed that the data from table A is looping over and over until it exausts table B.

JSON sample:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "BR_ID": 5,
    "ClientID": 237,
    "SLT_CODE": 12,
    "PURPOSE": 1,
    "PAMT": "100,000.00",
    "TERMS": 36,
    "PPMT_MODE": 4,
    "PPMT_MFAC": 0,
    "PPMT_MOD2": 4,
    "INT_RATE": 12,
    "PEN_RATE": 24,
    "OL_TEMP_APP_NO": "04152020566167",
    "APPLICATION_NO": null,
    "ActivityListID": 1,
    "DateRequested": "2020-04-15 14:22:36",
    "DateApproved": null,
    "ClientRemarks": "Every fight needs mending\nEvery start has an end\nLike the sunrise and the sunset\nThat's just how it is",
    "FilePath": "C:\\Users\\Personal\\laravel\\storage\\app\\public\\documents\\04152020566167.20200221_141512.jpg",
    "AttachmentName": "04152020566167.20200221_141512.jpg",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
}
```

Basically all the data throughout the loop is the same except `"FilePath"` and `"AttachmentName"` since they are the ones from table B.

Is there anyway where I can structure my JSON response as:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "BR_ID": 5,
    "ClientID": 237,
    "SLT_CODE": 12,
    "PURPOSE": 1,
    "PAMT": "100,000.00",
    "TERMS": 36,
    "PPMT_MODE": 4,
    "PPMT_MFAC": 0,
    "PPMT_MOD2": 4,
    "INT_RATE": 12,
    "PEN_RATE": 24,
    "OL_TEMP_APP_NO": "04152020566167",
    "APPLICATION_NO": null,
    "ActivityListID": 1,
    "DateRequested": "2020-04-15 14:22:36",
    "DateApproved": null,
    "ClientRemarks": "Every fight needs mending\nEvery start has an end\nLike the sunrise and the sunset\nThat's just how it is",
    "Attachments":
    [
        {
            "FilePath": "C:\\Users\\Personal\\laravel\\storage\\app\\public\\documents\\04152020566167.20200221_141512.jpg",
            "AttachmentName": "04152020566167.20200221_141512.jpg",
        },
        {
            "FilePath": "C:\\Users\\Personal\\laravel\\storage\\app\\public\\documents\\04152020566167.20200228_170949.jpg",
            "AttachmentName": "04152020566167.20200228_170949.jpg"
        }
    ]
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
}
```

This is my query:

```
$newLoans = Loans::
where('tblloanapp.ActivityListID', 1)
->leftJoin('tblattachments', 'tblattachments.OL_TEMP_APP_NO', '=', 'tblloanapp.OL_TEMP_APP_NO')
->get();
return response()->json($newLoans);
```

Comment: what's the relationship between `Attachments` and `Loans`?

Comment: @TsaiKoga ```Loans``` is the application form, the ```Attachments``` are the documents uploaded from the application form but put in a different table since a user can attach multiple attachments

Comment: then you need to build one-to-many  relationship between them

Answer (score 0):

**Model Code**

```
class Loans extends Model
    {
        public function attachments(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Attachments','application_id','id');
           //params: model name, reference column(foreign key), column from this table
        }    
    }
```

**Controller**

```
Loans::with('attachments')->where('tblloanapp.ActivityListID', 1)->get();
```

Hope this helps.
Let me know if in case it doesn't work

Comment: I've added the code. The return is ```return $this->hasMany('App\Attachments', 'OL_TEMP_APP_NO', 'OL_TEMP_APP_NO');``` but it gives an error ```Call to undefined relationship [tblattachments] on model [App\Loans].```

Comment: Is  application number have the primary  key In loan table ?

Comment: the entire table does have any key? If not, you have to make the primary key to the application number in the loan table.